# Insert new string into list and for it to hold the information

Tags: python

I'm learning Python and I'm wondering how you would insert a name into a list and for it to be held in that variable so the script can identify if it's seen you before.

Any help would be much appreciated

```
# Default People Already In List at program start
list = ['Bob','Jim',]
print("Hello, What\'s your name ?")
Name = input("Enter your Name: ")
if Name in list:
    print("Nice to meet you again" + Name)
else:
    list.insert(0, Name)
    print("Hi " + Name + ", Nice too meet you for the first time.")

# Troubleshoot
print(list)
```

Comment: Your code looks like it should work. What's wrong with it?

Comment: What about saving the list of names in another file and load it at the beginning of each run ? Will that suits you ?

Comment: Hi Aran, Yes it does kind of work. But the data isn't held into the list and forgets it when initialising the command again

Comment: As said above, store list to disk (look into the pickle library for instance). A nit: it's generally not a good idea to name a list variable `list` as you want to keep this keyword for type checking for instance.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea Nuageux. Would you mind instructing me or pointing me towards a link

Comment: I've read about saving into a type of data set within a pickle however I'm not too sure how this process works

Comment: You can write to a newline-separated text file, a csv, a pickle, or a json. I would recommend json as it's a ubiquitous standard which you can easily read.

Comment: File types what supports?

Comment: Sorry, I mean't the different file formats that you can integrate into Python such as Pickle, Json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will store it to a file, also its not a good practice to use built in functions and utilities as variable names. so I modified the name as lists

```
try:
    with open("listofnames.txt","r") as fd:
        lists=eval(fd.read())
except:
    lists=[['Bob','Jim',]]

print("Hello, What\'s your name ?")
Name = input("Enter your Name: ")
if Name in lists:
    print("Nice to meet you again", Name)
else:
    lists.insert(0, Name)
    with open("listofnames.txt","w") as f:
        f.write(str(lists))

    print("Hi " + Name + ", Nice too meet you for the first time.")

# Troubleshoot
print(lists)
```

Comment: Thank @Inder, It look's quite familiar to something I tried to do. However my result was blank save files.  I'll give it a shot again

Comment: @MitchG please see I just made a minor update when reading a file, it is very important otherwise it will throw an eroor

Comment: Yes there is one.  with open("listofnames.txt","r") as fd:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'listofnames.txt'

Comment: Look's like it doesn't automatically create the .txt

Comment: @MitchG you will have to create it for the first time I will make edits for that

Comment: No problem, I thought that was the problem. Was going to test and troubleshoot but I'm also negotiating chat

Comment: @MitchG It will work now, if the file doesn't exist it will assign the variable name for list in case it is the first time running the script on any machine.

Comment: I've had a look at the code and the "Nice to meet you again" works when you input the name for the first time and it stores it into the listofnames.txt .  However when you insert another name and try to refer back to the previously entered name it will output "Nice too meet you for the first time" When in fact the previous name is located in the .txt file

Comment: @MitchG kindly just do a copy paste of the newest edited answer , it was an indentation problem the print hi for first time was out of else

Comment: Thanks @Inder. Works like a whistle now. thanks for your support

Comment: Sorry for the ongoing questions. However I'm wondering what part of this string does ? "as fd:  lists=eval(fd.read())"

Comment: @MitchG when we wrote a file in order to do that simple we converted into string with line `f.write(str(lists))`, so now our list is saved as a string something that looks like `"['BOB','othernames']"`

Comment: so when we load this file it is still a string, we can't use it as a list, in order to get the list out of that string we are using `eval()`

Comment: So what eval does is it interprets and executes whats inside  " " or a string, so our string had a list in it which is evaluated and stored in a variable as a list not as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Your should rename your variables - here a short correction of your code, although it is looking good already! I changed the insert to append as well!

But it will obviously forget since the list is always initialized with Bob and Jim in it, and then you ask for the name - if is not Bob or Jim, it is new and therefore appended. But then your program ends, so when you start it new, your list is only populated with Bob & Jim again. You could put the whole construct in a "while True" construct to make the same question multiple times until you dont want to anymore!

EDIT: included the while (you can enter it numerous times if you just press "Enter" for the question! and put the list in the beginning, so it will not be initialized every time you run a new name! and important: if you see someone for the first time, include the print in the else-clause, otherwise it will be printed everytime, even if you saw the name before!

```
name_list = ['Bob','Jim']
while True:

    print("Hello, What\'s your name? ")
    input_name = input("Enter your Name: ")
    if str(input_name) in name_list:
        print("Nice to meet you again, " + input_name)
    else:
        name_list.append(input_name)
        print("Hi " + input_name + ", Nice too meet you for the first time.")

    # Troubleshoot
    print(name_list)

    if str(input("Another name? ")) == '':
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Thanks @Cut7er That's good to know. I'm very fascinated with Python, hopefully I'll get the hang of it soon

Comment: if the answer was useful for you, you could vote it up! same goes for Inder's answer as well :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did. This works with a CSV file.

```
# Load from file
list = []
listfile = open('list.csv', 'r+')
for name in listfile:
    list.append(name[:-1])

print("Hello, What\'s your name ?")
Name = input("Enter your Name: ")
if Name in list:
    print("Nice to meet you again " + Name)
else:
    print("Hi " + Name + ", Nice too meet you for the first time.")
    listfile.write(Name + "\n")  #adding to file

# Troubleshoot
print(list)
```

Comment: Thanks @Tharaka, I'll be sure to check it out